# Not getting values to LOV after Execution

Tags: oracle-adf, lov

I am Facing problem with Lov, I am having three lov fields in the page which are defined on  other viewObjects than current page viewObject. iam successfully able to bind them to the page i.e getting values by clicking the icon.

but the problem is while executing i am not getting any values for these fields, i tried to override  createInstanceFromResultSet() method in viewImpl class where iam getting  ids and setting values, for example by using appid in current row of Vo, iam setting appName, with out success. iam very new to ADF, any solutions. my jdevelper version is  oracle 11g release2

Actually my functionality is similar to POST-QUERY trigger in oracle forms, where you set the values based on id. 
Anybody has any guesses please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best way i found out is From ["Oracle® Fusion Middleware Fusion Developer's Guide for Oracle Application Development Framework Release1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/b31974/appendix_formstriggers.htm) is To have your View object based on multiple Entity Objects, joining in all the information you need in the query from the main table, as well as any auxiliary/lookup-value tables. so in one trip you can bring all the values from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way that you did bind these LOVs are wrong, follow this blog post https://blogs.oracle.com/prajkumar/entry/create_lov_in_adf_application it'll give you a heads up about the proper way to make LOVs

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get LOV value after execution in ADF, then please check both data types you defined on ViewObject and to those fields, apply Lov. If the data type of both the fields is different, then the submitted value is refresh and Lov field is showing blank.